# Python - determine if user is server or client

Tags: python, sockets

I'm writing a program that needs communication between two pc's. I know how to connect and send messages to each other. When the user opens the program, it should listen to connections. But if the user clicks 'connect', the program should stop listening for connections and connect to a user instead. How should I achieve that?
I've got this right now:

**MAIN**

```
@threaded
def getOnline(self):
   # fires when the user opens the program
    client.connect(PORT)

@threaded
def connect(self):
    # when the user clicks connect
    global IS_MASTER
    IS_MASTER = True
    print('Master:', IS_MASTER)
    if IS_MASTER:
        client.closeConnection()
        server.connect(CLIENT_IP, PORT)
```

**CLIENT**

```
class Client():

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def connect(self, port):
        print('Listening to connections')
        self.s.bind(('', port))
        self.s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = self.s.accept()
        print('Connected by:', addr)

    def closeConnection(self):
        print('Not listening any longer')
        self.s.close()
        sys.exit()
```

**SERVER**

```
class Server():

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def connect(self, host, port):
        self.s.connect((host, port))
        print('Connected to:', host)
```

Now when I click 'connect' I get: 'ConnectionAbortedError: [Errno 53] Software caused connection abort'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
Full Traceback

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 639, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 596, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/cedricgeerinckx/Dropbox/Redux/OSX/Redux.py", line 28, in wrapped_f
    ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cedricgeerinckx/Dropbox/Redux/OSX/Redux.py", line 204, in getOnline
    client.connect(PORT)
  File "/Users/cedricgeerinckx/Dropbox/Redux/OSX/Client.py", line 14, in connect
    conn, addr = self.s.accept()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 135, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
```

Comment: What's the full Traceback?

Comment: servers `bind`, `listen`, and `accept`, clients `connect`. you have it backwards

Comment: FYI, it looks like your `Client` class is listening on a port (which is what a server does), and your `Server` class is actively connecting to to a given address/port (which is what a Client does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception is being thrown inside your `getOnline` method, which is run on startup. That means the exception is occurring when the connection made in that method is shut down by the `connect` method. You should just handle the exception inside `getOnline`:

```
@threaded
def getOnline(self):
   # fires when the user opens the program
    try:
        client.connect(PORT)
    except ConnectionAbortedError as e:
        print("Connection shut down!")
```

Comment: Thank you! Will add try blocks around my code more often!